# Unable to read form inside uib-tabset

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to read a **form** from my controller. But I am getting undefined error. Here is my sample code.

HTML -

```
<uib-tabset name="tabMain" id="tabMain1">
<uib-tab heading="SomeTabName" name="tab1" id="tab1X">
    <form name="formId" class="form-horizontal" novalidate autocomplete="off"></form>
</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Controller -

```
$scope.formId.$setPristine();
```

The problem is $scope is not able to read the formId. Its saying undefined.

Please some one help me.

Thanks
Gulrej

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, add this line near the top:

```
$scope.forms = {};
```

Then, in your `<form>` element, change the name to `<form name="forms.formId"...`

Now, in the code where you're trying to access `$scope.formId` and getting the undefined error, change the code to `$scope.forms.formId`, and it should work.

I found the [answer here](https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2015/10/29/angularjs-scope-form-undefined/).

Answer (score 0):

The form only registers itself with the $scope of the controller after the controller has initially run. Therefore the $scope will return undefined even if everything is setup correctly.

In your example to react to the presence of theForm, you can setup a watcher on theForm to set debug text depending its presence:

```
$scope.$watch('theForm', function(theForm) {
    if(theForm) { 
        $scope.formDebugText = 'Form in Scope';
    }
    else {
        $scope.formDebugText = 'Form is Undefined';
    }        
});
```

Comment: Hi Deepankar, Thanks for the response. I have tried this already and it returned Undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue with a outer form with inputs spread between uib-tab.

After digging into [angularjs docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs), you need to expose a form outside of uib-tabset.

```
<form name="outerForm" class="tab-form-demo">
  <uib-tabset active="activeForm">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Form Tab">
      <form name="nestedForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="model.name"/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</form>

<pre>{{ outerForm.nestedForm | json }}</pre>
```

Or simply add one form who wrap uib-tabset

```
<form name="outerForm" class="tab-form-demo">
  <uib-tabset active="activeForm">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Form Tab">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="model.name"/>
        </div>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</form>
```